# Find the file differences between two repositories

Tags: git

I was wondering if it is possible to see individual file differences between a file (hello.txt) in my local repo and another repo of a different developer (on the same server)?

I know I could do a git pull and get the file changes, but is there an alternative way of avoiding over-writing my file?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the commit you want to compare to locally, then `git fetch` first.  This will fetch new commit objects from the remote repository, but will not change your HEAD or working tree.

Once you do have the commit, just do this:

```
git diff OTHERCOMMIT -- hello.txt
```

Where OTHERCOMMIT is the commit identifier (branch name, hash, etc.) for the commit you want to compare your local working copy of hello.txt against.